# Mysql error when run Python Django migrate using eclipse

Tags: python, mysql, django, eclipse

I just finished to make new project and create superuser. When I coded models.py and run migrate using eclipse, it throws error message and there is nothing in my Django admin.

Here is the error message.

```
System check identified some issues:
WARNINGS:
?: (mysql.W002) MySQL Strict Mode is not set for database connection 'default'
 HINT: MySQL's Strict Mode fixes many data integrity problems in MySQL, such as data truncation upon insertion, by escalating warnings into errors. 
 It is strongly recommended you activate it. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/databases/#mysql-sql-mode
 Operations to perform:
   Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
 Running migrations:
   No migrations to apply.
 Finished "C:\Users\ds\workspace\board\manage.py migrate" execution.
```

This is my models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from unittest.util import _MAX_LENGTH
from pip.cmdoptions import editable
from django.template.defaultfilters import default
from datetime import datetime

# Create your models here.


class User(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(_MAX_LENGTH=10)
    password = models.CharField(_MAX_LENGTH=10)
    join_date = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, default=datetime.now())


class todo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('id')
    title = models.TextField
    content = models.TextField
    date = models.DateField(editable=False, default=datetime.now())
```

Comment: Cool story, bro. Was there a question in there somewhere? https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Can you add the database section from settings.py to your question?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the documentation reference https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/databases/#mysql-sql-mode

And here is an example of the database configuration to avoid this warning and future errors:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'dbname',
        'USER': 'dbuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'dbpassword',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'",
        },
    }
}
```